# Writing 3d array into a file with different order

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I have 3d array of element (x,y,z) that is not in memory because of its possible size bigger than 4GB. In each loop, I can only get a 2D array of (x,z). Because of this restriction,

I can easily save them into a file of order (x,z,y) using

```
for (int iz=0;iz < nz; iz++)
    for (int ix=0;ix < nx; ix++)
         fwrite( (unsigned int *)(data+ix+iz*nx), element_size, 1, fp);
```

which is the same as

```
         fwrite( (unsigned int *)(data), element_size, nx*nz, fp);
```

But for a file of order (x,y,z), I have to do this for each iy

```
for (int iz=0;iz < nz; iz++) {
     fseek(fp,(iy*nx+iz*nx*ny)*element_size,SEEK_SET);
     fwrite( (unsigned int *)(data+iz*nx), element_size, nx, fp);
}
```

This is, however, really slow. Is there any better way to do this in VC++?

Comment: you have an array that doesn't exist?

Comment: @david - you have all of the code in front of you, and are very familiar with it. We are not, please try to make it easy for us to help. **please** paste the definition of the variable called `data` and `elelement_size`. It is very difficult to know what the pointer arithmetic might do without those. Worse, we can't help you check your assumptions, so we are all may all ASSuME

Comment: @david - go on, make me smile. Pleeeeeaaaaase paste the definition of `data` and `element_size` into your question. When we share the _code_, we can all understand with no misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C/C++ gives arrays organised by x as the largest contiguous slice, so data[7] contains every value for data[7][0-YMAX][0-ZMAX] a 2d unit, similarly data[7][3][0-ZMAX] is the next 1d unit

So what are the definitions of data and element_size?

When you write a subset of the array, it will have contigous elements of Z, and each of those Z slices will have a constant Y. If you do I/O with more than one set of contiguous set of Z values, you will have slices with contiguous Y.

So I don't understand:

> I can easily save them into a file of order (x,z,y) using ...

I may have misunderstood, but I don't think that code does that. I think it writes x,y,z elements